# can't import torchtext.legacy.data

Tags: python, import, pytorch, torchtext

[image]

as i know, from torchtext 0.9.0, torchtext.data and torchtext.dataset are moved to torchtext.legacy

but my 0.12.0 torchtext can't `import torchtext.legacy`
while it can `import torchtext.data`

I tried if it moved to torchtext.data again but I can't find any document

- torch.**version** == 1.11.0

Comment: In the [release notes](https://github.com/pytorch/text/releases) you can find: "  We have removed the legacy folder in this release which provided access to legacy datasets and abstractions. For additional information, please refer to the corresponding github issue (1422) and PR (1437)"

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same problem wtih the same versions. The only thing I was able to do about it is to install previous version of torchtext:

```
pip install torchtext==0.6.0
```

Only then was I wable to import the packs.